# Slim framework 404 error page showing not found error

Tags: php, slim

I'm changing the default 404 error page on my slim framework v2.

This is the code I'm using:

```
$app->notFound(function () use ($app) {
    $app->render('404.html');
});
```

However, I'm getting this error:

```
Message: View cannot render `404.html` because the template does not exist
```

I've the 404.html file in the same folder as my index.php which contains the Slim code. Also, just to check, I've copied the 404.html file in my slim folder also. Still, I'm getting the same error. Is there something related to template?

Answer (score 0):

[Solved]

I solved this issue using this code:

```
$app->notFound(function () use ($app) {
    $app->view->setTemplatesDirectory("Slim/");
    $app->render('404.html');
});
```

I just needed to set the Template Directory.